# Como aciona evento Onclick do botao com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso acionar o botão quando clicado. Fiz ele em jquery de forma genérica passando o parâmetro de determinado botão para executar o script para o mesmo.

```
<button id="buttonprofissional" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="profissional">Não tenho endereço profissional </button>
<button id="buttoncomplementar" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="complementar">Não tenho endereço complementar </button>


<script>
$(document).ready(function($endereco){
    $("button" + $endereco).click(function(){
        $("pais_"+$endereco).removeAttr('required');
        $("pais_"+$endereco).hide();
        $("uf_"+$endereco).removeAttr('required');
        $("uf_"+$endereco).hide();
        $("municipio_"+$endereco).removeAttr('required');
        $("municipio_"+$endereco).hide();
        $("bairro_"+$endereco).removeAttr('required');
        $("bairro_"+$endereco).hide();
        $("tipo_logradouro_"+$endereco).removeAttr('required');
        $("tipo_logradouro_"+$endereco).hide();
        $("titulo_patente_"+$endereco).removeAttr('required');
        $("titulo_patente_"+$endereco).hide();
        $("preposicao_"+$endereco).removeAttr('required');
        $("preposicao_"+$endereco).hide();
        $("logradouro_"+$endereco).removeAttr('required');
        $("logradouro_"+$endereco).hide();
        $("numero_"+$endereco).removeAttr('required');
        $("numero_"+$endereco).hide();
        $("complemento_"+$endereco).removeAttr('required');
        $("complemento_"+$endereco).hide();
        $("origem_"+$endereco).removeAttr('required');
        $("origem_"+$endereco).hide();
        $("email_"+$endereco).removeAttr('required');
        $("email_"+$endereco).hide();
        $("telefone_"+$endereco).removeAttr('required');
        $("telefone_"+$endereco).hide();
        $("celular_"+$endereco).removeAttr('required');
        $("celular_"+$endereco).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: de onde vem $endereco ?

Comment: O que é `$endereco = this.value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso queira manipular os elementos com base no `value` dos `buttons` *oque é meio estranho*, basta fazer isso...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 /* looping nos botões */
 $('button').each(function(b) {
   
    /* pega o value de cada um */
    var bv = $(this).val(); 
    
    /* atribui um evento de click para da um
    
    repare que o botão está concatena com o value */
    $('#button' + bv).on('click', function(){
    
     /* aqui você tem o valor
      e pode escolher o elemento que deseja manipular
      que contenha esse valor no id */
      
     $('#button' + bv).hide();
      
      $('#li' + bv).hide();
      $('#p' + bv).hide();
      $('#span' + bv).hide();
      $('#div' + bv).hide();
      
    });
    
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="buttonprofissional" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="profissional">Não tenho endereço profissional </button>
<button id="buttoncomplementar" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="complementar">Não tenho endereço complementar </button>

<li id="licomplementar">li</li>
<p id="pcomplementar">p</p>
<span id="spancomplementar">span</span>
<div id="divcomplementar">div</div>
```